# typescript/raven.d.ts, line: 205 Cannot find name 'unknown' while installing npm in ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, npm

I am getting this error while I am doing **npm install** in ionic project.

[image]

Please find package.json file here

http://keepnote.cc/package.json

Comment: try to install yarn...https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1193

Comment: Hi @paresh-gami, If one of the answers provided answered your questions please mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could remove your `node_modules/` folder and then reinstall the dependencies from `package.json`.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

Comment: Already tried but not working. Also tried with mac and windows. Getting same error

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot find name 'unknown'` is appearing because you're likely using Typescript 2, and raven.js is using the Typescript 3 type `'unknown'`

Either upgrade your project to use Typerscript 3, or downgrade raven.js to a version that supports Typescript 2.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your local node-module's raven.js folder with the older one and then try to rebuild  **ng build**
This way I solved my issue.